# Apple TV lag and connecting to Time Capsule

Tags: appletv, time-capsule

I have a 3rd gen Apple TV that I connect to my Mac, but I have issues with Airplay Display, namely that videos I try to stream from my Mac lag terribly.

I recently obtained a Time Capsule which I use as a router, but I would like to know if I can somehow connect it to my Apple TV, i.e. play videos stored on the Time Capsule hard disk.

I was also told that connecting my Apple TV to Time Capsule would improve the streaming speed and resolve the lag problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hardwiring the apple tv to the TC does refuce the lag cr wifi, but won't change any download lag.

Have mine hardwired and no issues...

Comment: How do I hardwire it? Just plug it to the back of the TC?

Comment: Use the networking sockets that both have. If you have other devices next the apple tv then get a small router box.